# How to change a lot of if/else where class should be returned in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, optimization

My eyes are bleed when I see a method with a lot of if/else statements in one method.
And I'd like to fix that somehow. 
Method is:

```
    private Class getMapType(String header) {
    if (header.equals(Bean01.getHeader())) {
        return Bean01.class;
    } else if (header.equals(Bean02.getHeader())) {
        return Bean02.class;
    } else if (header.equals(Bean03.getHeader())) {
        return Bean03.class;
    } else if (header.equals(Bean04.getHeader())) {
        return Bean04.class;
    } else
        logger.log(Logger.FATAL, "File does not exist");
    return null;
}
```

`getHeader()` method is different for each class.

So, how can I rework it?

Comment: Does `Bean01.getHeader()` always return the same `String` or does it vary?  Likewise with the other classes?  If the headers don't change, you could set up a `Map<String,Class<?>>` and look up headers in that.

Comment: You can use switch-case

Comment: You can use Class.forName(str), when str will iterate over all classes (Bean01.. Bean04) and then use reflection to call the function getHeader

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem, `getHeader()` is the same for Bean01, but it is different for e.g. Bean02, etc. 
How do you see Map<String,Class<?>> in this case?

Comment: I see it exactly as @SergheyBishyr shows in his answer.  It only works if each class always has the same header - and that's what my earlier comment was asking.

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use `static final Map`

```
private static final Map<String, Class> TYPE_MAPPING = new ImmutableMap.Builder()
  .put("Bean01", Bean01.class)
  .put("Bean02", Bean02.class)
  .put("Bean03", Bean03.class)
  .build();

private Class getMapType(String header) {
  return TYPE_MAPPING.get(header);
}
```

Comment: You've beat me to it by 10 seconds :D! Take my +1

Comment: @SergheyBishyr thanks. It looks nice. 
But I have one more stupid question: where do you get `ImmutableMap.Builder()`? Please specify an import line.

Comment: `import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.Builder;`

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: @TobiasGeiselmann Please don't! `google-collections` is [seven years old](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.collections/google-collections), the current name is [guava](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava).

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use reflections:

```
private Class getMapType(String header) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
        if (header.equals(Class.forName("com.mycompany.Bean0"+i).getMethod( "getHeader").invoke(null)))
            return Class.forName("com.mycompany.Bean0"+i);

    logger.log(Logger.FATAL, "File does not exist");
    return null;
}
```

You have to change class name in `forName` method (it must be fully qualified).

Comment: Bean classes have different names. I called them like `Bean0 + i` just like a simple example.

Comment: You can keep them in array and use `list.get(i)` instead of class name.

Comment: @HorukTaras Or keep classes names in array and use `for each` loop.

Comment: I'd really wouldn't recommend doing this as reflection is hacky and slow. You lose the compile time check of the existence of the classes. But I'd recommend using it for initializing the `ImmutableMap` for the accepted answer (but only if the list is very long). You still have no compile time check, but you have a runtime check running very soon. You can be sure it tests the existence of all classes whenever one is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using switch (Java 1.7 onwards Switch works with String):

```
  private Class getMapType(String header) {
      switch(header):
case "Bean01":
    return Bean01.class;
case "Bean02": 
    return Bean02.class;
case "Bean03": 
    return Bean03.class;
case "Bean04": 
    return Bean04.class;
default: 
    logger.log(Logger.FATAL, "File does not exist");
    return null;
```

}